# checking words in a dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary, lookup

I need to determine if an unknown 5 or 6 letter string is a valid word, i.e. is in the dictionary. I could submit the string/word to an online dictionary, but I need to check this string/word, which will be different each time, for about 100 to 150 times. This seems to be a bit time consuming.

My next thought would be to try to get a dictionary program of my own. It would need to be in Java as my program is written in Java. Does the Java API already have a class for doing this? Can I get a descent one that someone has already coded, and all I have to do is submit the string/word to it?

My program is not being used for spell checking. I want to write a program for unscrambling the Jumbled Word Puzzles when I get stuck on a scrambled word. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the open source dictionaries and load it into a database:  ftp://ftp.cerias.purdue.edu/pub/dict/ and ftp://ftp.ox.ac.uk/pub/wordlists/

Comment: actually you might do better using a Trie if you're going to roll your own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332104/find-the-existence-of-a-word-in-a-large-dictionary

Answer (score 1):

For scrambled words, you might want to look at the [Jumble algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumble), an implementation of which is seen [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jumble#Jumble).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need spell checking this would be really easy.  Just load all your words into a HashSet and then check to see if that set contains the word you want to test.  There are tons of [word lists](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/) available.

If you do need a spell checker, then check out aspell or other free APIs.

Answer (score 0):

[aspell](http://aspell.net/) and its associated word lists and dictionaries might be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think [aspell](http://aspell.net) has a Java version.

edit: actually it looks like you might do better with this aspell spinoff called [Jazzy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jazzy/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check some wordlist:
http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/

This page has some word lists in text format, so you can process in Java yourself, most easily using a HashSet. You need to use more efficient data structures if efficiency is important.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try [Peter Norvig's spelling checker](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html).  I think it's an elegant way to get 80-90% accuracy.