# Get the number of spelling mistakes in a string: Java

Tags: jakarta-ee, dictionary, spell-checking

I am working on an application where I require to count the number of spelling mistakes made by a user in the given answer. I was about to try google's spell checker service but it seems that service has been axed.

which will be the best library to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.
Neeraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question (or one like it) seems to have been asked (and answered) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559510/looking-for-java-spell-checker-library).

In a nutshell, [Jazzy](http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/) might do what you're looking for, but it seems to be limited by its English-only dictionary source.

Comment: Thanks. I want it for English only. Do we have any example on how we get number of incorrect words?

Comment: It seems that Jazzy might be overkill for what you're looking to do, since it also provides suggestions for misspelled words. It seems that it would make more sense for you to simply use Java's StringTokenizer class to iterate over the words in the user's input string and then, for each word, search a dictionary for the presence of that word. You can find a standard UNIX dictionary file at http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/linuxwords provided by Duke University. For performance reasons, it would make sense to read the dictionary file into memory before searching through it.

Comment: Indeed, the question and suggestions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032064/checking-words-in-a-dictionary seem to be a closer match to your question here.