# What would be an efficient way to see if a word exist when comparing to hundreds of thousands of words?

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, dictionary

Iv'e been working with objective-c for while and I want to attempt to build an app. The app will be similar to a scrabble type of game. There are going to be drag and drop tiles (I already know how to program this) and a submit button. The only thing that I'm having trouble with is figuring out how I am going to compare the letters on the board to hundreds of thousands words without bogging down my program to much. What I have in mind, so far, is to store these the words in a database. Does objective-c have any kind of built in api that can access a standard dictionary database? I'm not referring to a dictionary array but rather an actual database with words and possibly definitions. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the existence of a word in a large dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332104/find-the-existence-of-a-word-in-a-large-dictionary)

Comment: regex pattern matching on a list of database stored words seems appropriate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [Lexicontext](http://www.lexicontext.com/), it's $20, but it's worth it in my opinion, is extremely fast, there's a demo, and it contains a API for formatting definitions with CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're happy with the $20 solution.  For the more adventuresome, the data structure you'd want to learn about is [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Imagine a tree with 26 children of the root, one for each letter in the alphabet.  Now imagine that each child has 26 children, too.  You can spell any word of length N by taking N steps from root to leaf.  Now imagine that you prune the tree so it contains only valid words.  That's your (very fast) word validator.  It will take as long on average as your average word length.

Comment: +1. A very fundamental data structure that all programmers should be familiar with.

Comment: Actually you want a [DAWG not a Trie](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=115).

Comment: Are there any example of doing this in actual code for us little less experienced programmers?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how "Scrabble-like" your game actually is....

Are you going to be validating the word when the player presses submit?

That's not how Scrabble works. The player can play *any* (non)word so long as the opponents do not challenge the word.

So you'll need word validation in the "challenge" system, but it shouldn't happen as soon as the player plays the word. An unscrupulous player could then just place "maybe" words and press submit, to see if it actually is a valid word.

Comment: that's a good point. I was thinking more like validating the word as soon as the user presses the submit button. And if the word is invalid, then don't let them play it.

Comment: I find this being up-voted odd as the poster is not asking for assistance on game design, nor the intricacies of the features of his app.